# validating response outside of context manager?

Tags: locust

[EDITED: I realized after reading response that I oversimplified my question.]

I am new to Locust and not sure how to solve this problem.

I have function (call it "get_doc") that is passed a locust.HttpSession() and uses it to issue an HTTP request.  It gets the response and parses it, returning it up several layers of call.  One of these higher-level calls looks at the returned, parsed document to decide if the response was what was expected or not.  If not, I want Locust to mark the request/response  as failed.  A code sketch would be:

```
class MyUser (HttpUser):
    @task
    def mytask(self):
        behavior1 (self.client)

def bahavior1(session):
    doc = get_doc(session, url1)
    if not doc_ok (doc):
        ??? how to register a failure with Locust here...
    doc2 = get_doc(session, url2)
    ...

def get_doc(http_session, url):
    page = http_session.get(url)
    doc = parse (page)
    return doc
```

There may be several behavior[n] functions and several Locust users calling them.

A constraint is that I would like to keep Locust-specific stuff out of bahavior1() so that I can call it with an ordinary Requests session.  I have tried to do something like this in get_doc() (the catch_response parameter and success/fail stuff is actually conditionalized on 'session' being an HttpSession object):

```
def get_doc (session, meth, url):
    resp = session.request (meth, url, catch_response=True)
    doc = parse (resp.content)
    doc.logfns = resp.success, resp.failure
    return doc
```

and then in behavior1() or some higher up-chain caller I can

```
doc.logfns[1]("Document not as expected")
```

or

```
doc.logfns[0]  # Looks good!
```

Unfortunately this is not working; the calls to them produce no errors but Locust doesn't seem to record any successes or failures either.  I am not sure if it should work or I bungled something in my code.  Is this feasible?  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you use catch_response=True you *must* use a with block. Otherwise (as you have noticed) it does nothing at all.

Comment: OK, I was afraid of that.  I'll look for another approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make get_doc a context manager, call .get with catch_response=True and yield instead of return inside it. Similar to how it is done here: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/2cbbdda9ae37b6cbb0a11cf69aca80b164198aec/locust_plugins/users/rest.py#L22

And then use it like this

```
def mytask(self):
    with get_doc(self.client, url) as doc:
        if not doc_ok(doc):
            doc.failure(”doc was not ok :(”)
```

If you want, you can add the parsed doc as a field on the response before yielding in your doc function, or call doc.failure() inside doc_ok.

Comment: I was hoping for some way to avoid a context manager but realize I didn't make clear why -- I've edited the original question to add more details.  My apologies for not being clearer the first time around.